# Running multi-queries in MySQL (for SphinxQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby, sphinx

Currently we're relying on Sphinx's PHP library to manage our faceted search, which depends on the ability to use Sphinx's multi-queries feature.

The latest Sphinx search documentation describes how to perform the same multi-query procedure in SphinxQL, via MySQL.  It gives an example using PHP.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.4.html#sphinxql-multi-queries

Do any MySQL gems exist for ruby that support multi-queries in this way?

I'm looking at the mysql2 gem, which seems to be the latest thing, but it doesn't appear to support it.  Am I still at a loss when it comes to Sphinx multi-queries in ruby?

I'm going to write a client that supports them in the next few days at work anyway if not, but obviously SphinxQL would make this *much* easier.  I'd also rather not have to make my gem connect to two different protocols for RT indexes (which can only be written to via SphinxQL).  It seems like SphinxQL is basically where it's at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own gem, which includes a little wrapper around MySQL.  Not a fully-fledged mysql client, but a minimal bridge in order to support SphinxQL.

You can see the gem here: https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus

And the C extension here: https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus/blob/master/ext/oedipus/oedipus.c

Answer (score 0):

It appears the ruby-mysql gem supports this: https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/blob/master/lib/mysql.rb#L406-419

I assume it is processing this correctly.  It says 'execute', but in reality it appears to simply be fetching the next set of results from a query that was already executed.

```
  # execute next query if multiple queries are specified.
  # === Return
  # true if next query exists.
  def next_result
    return false unless more_results
    check_connection
    @fields = nil
    nfields = @protocol.get_result
    if nfields
      @fields = @protocol.retr_fields nfields
      @result_exist = true
    end
    return true
  end
```

There is reference to it here too: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/ (Under 'Multiple Statements')